# Prove that lim sup $x_n$ for infinitely many n.

Tags: analysis

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a real sequence and $r$ a real number. Prove that $\lim \sup_{n\to\infty}x_n<r$ implies $x_n<r$ for $n$ large enough. Prove that $\lim \sup_{n\to\infty}x_n>r$ implies $x_n>r$ for infinitely many $n$.

I am not sure how to prove this. Could anyone give me any hints or tips?

Comment: What do you know about lim sup?

Comment: Use the definition on $\limsup$ to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $l = \limsup_n x_n$. This means $l = \lim_n \sup_{k \ge n} x_k$.

Suppose $l <r$. Choose $N$ large enough so that for $n \ge N$, we have $\sup_{k \ge n} x_k \le l+\frac{l+r}{2}$. It follows that $x_n \le l+\frac{l+r}{2} < r$ for $n \ge N$.

Now notice that $n \mapsto \sup_{k \ge n} x_k$ is non-increasing, hence $\sup_{k \ge n} x_k \ge l$ for all $n$. It follows that for all $\epsilon>0$, the set $\{n | x_n \ge l-\epsilon \}$ is infinite (otherwise $\sup_{k \ge n} x_k \le l-\epsilon$ for some $n$, which contradicts the definition of $l$).
Then choose $\epsilon = l-r >0$ for the second part.

Comment: hey thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: hey @copper.hat can i ask you another question?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522043/finding-delta-with-given-a-f-l-and-epsilon

Comment: @Dafty: I started answering your question and it was deleted half way through!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Remember that
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sup_{k\geq n}x_k\right].
$$
Then, use (or prove, if you don't have it at your disposal) this fact:

**Lemma:** If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L>M$, then there exists $N$ such that $a_n>M$ for $n\geq N$.

(This result may be easier to prove directly than the one that you started with.)