# Notation when computing the probability of limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

I want to demonstrate the issue using an example. Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be iid. with $P(X_n> x)=e^{-x}$. We want to show $\forall \epsilon > 0$ 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln n}\ge 1-\epsilon \  a.s$$

To do this the Borel-Cantelli theorem is used. The argument goes like this:
$$P(X_n> \ln n(1-\epsilon))=e^{-\ln n(1-\epsilon)}=n^{-(1-\epsilon)}$$ which is not summable. Therefore, for $A_n:=\{X_n>\ln n (1-\epsilon)\}$ we get
 $$P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n)=1$$

Now in the script I am using it is concluded that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln n}\ge 1-\epsilon \  a.s$ which is what we wanted to show.

Why is $$P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n> \ln (1-\epsilon)\})=1$$ the same as $$P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n> \ln (1-\epsilon))=P(\omega\in\Omega\colon \limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)>\ln n(1-\epsilon)) = 1$$

Comment: What $\limsup \{X_n > (1-\varepsilon)\ln(n) \}$ means? It is $\bigcap_N \bigcup_{n > N} \{X_n > (1-\varepsilon)\ln(n) \}$. In other words, there exists a sequence $(n_N)_{N \in \mathbb N}$ such that $n_N \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$ for which we have $X_{n_N} \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(n_N)} > 1-\varepsilon \}$. You showed that it happens almost surely, so it means that $\limsup$ of the sequence $\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}$ is greater (or equal since it's a limit process) than $1-\varepsilon$ almost surely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sequence of r.v.s. $\{Z_n\}$ and a constant $z$,
$$
\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_n> z\right\}\subseteq \left\{Z_n> z \text{ i.o.}\right\}\subseteq \left\{Z_n\ge z \text{ i.o.}\right\}\subseteq\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}Z_n\ge z\right\},
$$
which follows from the properties of sequences of real numbers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "properties of sequences"? Can you show some the inclusions, this would be helpful!

Comment: I mean that for each $\omega$, $\{Z_n(\omega)\}$ is just a sequence of real numbers $\{z_n\}$. So, for example, $\limsup z_n >z$ implies $z_n>z$ for infinitely many $n$'s and, hence, the first inclusion holds (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521958/prove-that-lim-sup-x-n-for-infinitely-many-n)).